# match regex between varying number of characters

Tags: regex

The following regex matches "EXAMPLETEXT" in my example below but I'd like to be able to use `\d*` to match one or more digits instead of `\d\d`. Is that possible or is there a better method?

String:

```
09.04.EXAMPLETEXT.14
```

Regex:

```
(?<=\.\d\d\.)(.*)(?=\.)
```

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: I'm using Python but trying to get the regex running in regex101 first

Comment: It is very simple: ([0-9.]*)(.*?)([0-9.]*)

Comment: Can you give some more examples of strings you'd like your regex to match (including what substring you'd like to capture) and strings you don't want it to match?

Comment: If you always have two digits followed by a dot (and don't know how many), then there is a better method to do this: `((?:\d{2}\.)*)`

Comment: Or this: `(?:\d+\.)+(.*)(?:\.\d+)+` https://regex101.com/r/pP6lX7/1

Comment: that last one works, thanks a lot

Comment: didn't realize that regex behaved slightly differently in different languages and that regex101 lets you choose your language.

Comment: ArnoVR, it's good form to mark the correct Answer as such. Looks like Jan called it, is that right?

Comment: sure I tried to mark the correct answer, maybe I need more rep for that?

Comment: ah found Jan's answer below, was looking for a way to mark in the comments, oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use lookbehind at all for this, a regex such as this would work:

```
(?:\d+\.)+(.*)(?:\.\d+)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/pP6lX7/1

Or if you want to be able to match the string inside some other text

```
(?:\d+\.)+([^\s]*)(?:\.\d+)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/sB5mB2/1

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `*` or `+` or `?` quantifiers inside lookbehind assertions in perl,java,python regexes (they won't support variable length lookbehind). But you can use those symbols inside lookbehind in c# family.

If your're on php or perl, you may use `\K`

```
\.\d*\.\K(.*)(?=\.)
```

Another hack in all languages is,  just print all the captured chars.

```
\.\d*\.(.*)\.
```

**Example for greedy:**

```
>>> s = "09.043443.EXAMPLETEXT.14"
>>> re.search(r'\.\d*\.(.*)\.', s).group(1)
'EXAMPLETEXT'
```

**Example for non-greedy match:**

```
>>> re.search(r'\.\d*\.(.*?)\.', s).group(1)
'EXAMPLETEXT'
```

Use negated char class.

```
>>> re.search(r'\.\d*\.([^.]*)\.', s).group(1)
'EXAMPLETEXT'
```

Comment: @maraca I just modified his regex `\d\d` with `\d*` without touching the functionality of greedy match.

Comment: @AvinashRaj ok, but wouldn't that be `\d{2}` (or maybe `\d+`) not completely sure what the question is, just alternatives.

Comment: `\K` used because to achieve the functionality of variable length lookbehind.